# Stuck on a javascript function for my game

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, hasownproperty

so I'm creating a function to accept two arguments,

1. the first parameter is the name of the person
2. the second is how much they have already donated.

Each individual is assigned to an array depending on how much they are expected to donate. people in variable

- a are expected to donate 6,
- b should donate 5 and
- c donate 4.

I want the function to return how many more donations should the individual make but here is the problem: no matter what name I input into the console log, it always assumes the person is from var a. Did I miss something here?

```
function findDonationRequirement(name, num){

var a = ["shad0vvfax","DarthPolekat","TheSchwartz",
"Johnnie SR91","Brodie", "HolyPaladin", "Kraven", "Dan Solo",
"Khorathian812", "KingWilliam"];

var b = ["Infantry0223","Ru Baruba Maral","Gray JediTim", "Moof Milker",
"Andain", "Cori Starfire", "Nassyy", "Roylas Trebla", "DarthPapirrin",
"MaximusGiganticus", "Wardai", "George3PO", "Revan2017", "Ravishing Dirk",
"dowi", "dogamidstwind", "SpinelessAce", "Devilscut88", "Dagez",
"The Buckster", "ddpf", "WoollyLemurToes", "Emeralthys Phantom  2060095",
"Lightnara1", "JoLy NYC",   "Ccube19", "Anectet Heat", "BigBadBoneDaddy",
"Grizzy", "Zanzibar", "Jesse", "BhMojo", "Kuu Raama", "Jay Fury", "N8Dog",
"Whiskytangofoxtrot"];

var c = ["KingofG0nd0r", "Chrome Cobra", "Bad Rongo", "TK421"];

if (a.hasOwnProperty(name)) {return 6 - num}

else if (b.hasOwnProperty(name)) {return 5 - num}

else if (c.hasOwnProperty(name)) {return 4 - num}

else "Not on list";}

console.log(findDonationRequirement("KingofG0nd0r", 3));
```

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` will not find elements in an array - you should only use that if you're searching an object.

Comment: Out of curiosity: where are these names from? :) And `a.includes(name)` ...

Comment: you should really read the documentation on the methods before using them

Comment: They are from a video game :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use indexOf()

```js
function findDonationRequirement(name, num) {

  var a = ["shad0vvfax", "DarthPolekat", "TheSchwartz",
    "Johnnie SR91", "Brodie", "HolyPaladin", "Kraven", "Dan Solo",
    "Khorathian812", "KingWilliam"
  ];

  var b = ["Infantry0223", "Ru Baruba Maral", "Gray JediTim", "Moof Milker",
    "Andain", "Cori Starfire", "Nassyy", "Roylas Trebla", "DarthPapirrin",
    "MaximusGiganticus", "Wardai", "George3PO", "Revan2017", "Ravishing Dirk",
    "dowi", "dogamidstwind", "SpinelessAce", "Devilscut88", "Dagez",
    "The Buckster", "ddpf", "WoollyLemurToes", "Emeralthys Phantom  2060095",
    "Lightnara1", "JoLy NYC", "Ccube19", "Anectet Heat", "BigBadBoneDaddy",
    "Grizzy", "Zanzibar", "Jesse", "BhMojo", "Kuu Raama", "Jay Fury", "N8Dog",
    "Whiskytangofoxtrot"
  ];

  var c = ["KingofG0nd0r", "Chrome Cobra", "Bad Rongo", "TK421"];

  if (a.indexOf(name)>-1) {
    return 6 - num
  } else if (b.indexOf(name)>-1) {
    return 5 - num
  } else if (c.indexOf(name)>-1) {
    return 4 - num
  } else {
    return "Not on list";
  }
}

console.log(findDonationRequirement("Ccube19", 3));
console.log(findDonationRequirement("Chrome bra", 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `a.hasOwnProperty(name)` use `a.indexOf(name) > 0`

`hasOwnProperty` is an Object method to look up the property with the name `name`

`indexOf` is an Array method to look up a literal or object's position inside an Array. When it is not found it returns `-1`. So play with its value to figure out if it exists in the `a` Array.

more on `indexOf` here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf